# Seting enctype in AngularJS using ngResource

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, ngresource

I'm using Angular's $resource to upload a file.
I need to set the encoding to mulipart/form-data, but I can't find anyway to set enctype in $resource.

Is that possible? In other words can $resource be used for file uploading or do I have to go deeper and use $http, modifying the header using the config argument?

What is the right way to go about POSTing a multipart/form-data form in AngularJS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried doing something like this

```
$resource(
      url,
      {},
      {
        upload: {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {enctype:'multipart/form-data'}
        },
      }
)
```

Update: See this fiddle to understand how to use the update once the enctype has been change http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/doLhmgL6/

Comment: How do you send data when you do resource.update(<what_goes_here>? How do you use this?

Comment: in fiddler data about 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: How would you attach file to resource? Here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819937/seting-enctype-in-angularjs-using-ngresource?rq=1